# What parts of the universe are shared between characters?

Tags: starbound

I beat The Ruin in Starbound last night and almost immediately started a new character.

Upon making it to the Outpost, I was startled to discover that the racial NPCs I had unlocked with each artifact were already at the Outpost! They were even selling me stuff and offering quests!

This leads me to wonder, what else is constant between multiple characters? If I go to the same planet on 2 characters, will all the buildings I've built with the first be there? Can I use this as a way to transfer gear between my characters?

Answer (score 6):

The Universe (Planets) carries over between characters. Every planet and every structure on it is the same between all your characters, even if you delete your old ones and start all-new.

That is because the Universe is saved in a seperate file that is independent of your characters.

That means you can either reset the world for all your characters or not at all. That might sound bad, but considering there are millions of planets in the game, you shouldn't worry about running out of stuff to do.

EDIT: Ships do not carry over as they are saved with your character

Comment: What about ships?

Comment: ships do not carry over, no

Comment: So is there a way to transfer items between characters?

Comment: @Raven yes, simply put it in some storage place on some planet/structure. Every character loads up the same universe file, so ALL things related to it carry over.

Comment: Does the new player start on or near the previous player's starting planets?

Comment: @PrivatePansy The starting planet never changes. It is always the same for all your characters. Actually, the whole first solar system is.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray That's not true - I've made 3 characters, and they've started on 3 separate (albeit, Lush) planets.